# Unframed highlighted box

Tags: boxes

How can I create unframed highlighted box like this:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can load the `framed` package and the `shaded*` environment:

```
...
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\colorlet{shadecolor}{lightgray}
...
\begin{document}
...
\begin{shaded*}
\textbf{Example: Decision space for a College Admission Decision}\\
The decision space for a college admission decision consists of  the (potentially unobservable, hopefully unpredictable) information …
\end{shaded*}
...
\end{document}
```

It can break across pages. The non-starred version bleeds into the margins.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with `tcolorbox` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{mybox}[1]{%
    colbacktitle=gray!30,
    coltitle=black,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    colback=gray!30,
    colframe=gray!30,
    sharp corners,
    title=#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{mybox}{Example: Decision space for a College Admissions Decision}
The decision space for a college admissions decision consists of  the \dots
\end{mybox}
\end{document}
```

[image]